# syntax highlighting between matching parenthesis

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

Say I hava a LaTeX document open in Vim, and I want to highlight every occurence of

```
{\color{red} ... }
```

(where the dots are supposed to symbolize some contents), that is, I want to have `{\color{red}`, `}` and everything between these highlighted. This I have done with

```
:syn region WarningMsg start=+{\\color{red}+ end=+}+
```

but I have the problem that, if I write something like `{\color{red} some{thing} important}`, then it is only `{\color{red} some{thing}` which gets highlighted, because Vim of course mathces the first occurrence of `}`. How can I make this Highlighting rule so that it skips matching curly brackets? Even multiple levels of such.

Comment: You want to get the largest possible match, instead of the smallest one (just throwing it out there). I have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: @Keyser: Not necessarily the largest possible match. It is important that it only ignores matching parenthesis. I would not want it to highlight all between the first occurrence of `{\color{red}` in my document to the last occurrence of `}`. Since my document obviously ends with `\end{document}` this would just highlight the rest of the file from the first occurrence of `{\color{red}`.

Comment: So to clarify: You want to allow one extra closing curly bracket when you stumble upon an opening curly bracket. I think that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity it is better to give each syntax region a bespoke name, and then link it to a standard colour group. I have renamed your original region `redTeX`.

You need to define a second region, `innerBrace`, defining the braces you want to ignore, and mark this region as transparent. Then `redTeX` should be marked to contain the transparent region, which it will then ignore.

```
syn region innerBrace start=+{+ end=+}+ transparent contains=redTeX
syn region redTeX start=+{\\color{red}+ end=+}+ contains=innerBrace
hi link redTeX WarningMsg
```

Note that in this case there is the added subtlety that `redTeX` itself matches as an `innerBrace`. I fixed this by marking `innerBrace` as containing `redTeX`.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: This works nicely, except that it does not allow you to have multiple levels of braces, e.g if you write `{\color{red} some{thing {very}} impoartant}` then it only highlights `{\color{red} some{thing {very}}`. I realized that this can be fixed by replacing `contains=redTeX` with `contains=redTeX,innerBrace`, in the definition of `innerBrace`, so that a set of braces can contain another set of braces. Should there be anything wrong with fixing it in this way? Thanks.

Comment: Your fix should be okay. Does it break the original problem with a single level of braces?