# Correctly match begin and end curly braces in syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting

I am customizing `tex.vim` syntax file to make LaTeX macro `\PVerb` to be hightlighted the same way as be `\verb`. I mimicked the line for `\verb` in the syntax file, adding the following line:

```
syn region texZone      start="\\PVerb{"            end="}\|%stopzone\>"
```

That said, I want to hightlight text region from `\PVerb{` to its matching `}`.

But, if there are `{}`'s inside `\PVerb{...}`, the enclosing `}` will be matched too early, e.g.,

```
\PVerb{{text1}...{text2}}
```

The `...{text2}` part won't get hightlighted because of the `}` before it.

So how to bypass the `}` in these cases, which is not the correct matching brace?

I have tried suggestion presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880805/syntax-highlighting-between-matching-parenthesis), but <s>couldn't get it work</s> the highlighted region extended *beyond* the matching `}`.

This is what I have tried (added `innerBrace` as suggested by @Ingo Karkat):

```
syn region innerBrace       start=+{+               end=+}+ transparent contains=texZone,innerBrace
syn region texZone      start="\\PVerb{"            end="}\|%stopzone\>" contains=innerBrace
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

You can see the normal text on line 3 is highlighted verbatim as well.

If I delete `contains=innerBrace` in `syn region texZone`, the following is what I got:

[image]

Comment: That works for me. If you use `syn region innerBrace       start=+{+               end=+}+ transparent contains=texZone,innerBrace`, it'll even deal with nested `{ ... { ...`

Comment: @IngoKarkat Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my description. The problem is that the hightlighted region extend beyond the matching `}`. As you can see from my screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `innerBrace` already matches the `{` that concludes the start of the `\PVerb{` region start. I was able to correct this via a *negative look-behind* on the `innerBrace` region start, disallowing a match when there's `\PVerb` immediately before it. This restricts that syntax group to true *inner* braces, and the spanning and nesting works.

```
syn region innerBrace   start=+\%(\\PVerb\)\@<!{+   end=+}+ transparent contains=innerBrace
syn region texZone      start="\\PVerb{"            end="}\|%stopzone\>" contains=innerBrace
```

Also, `innerBrace` need not contain `texZone` again (as it itself is already only contained in such).

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Ingo. It finally worked. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, for me the `{` of `\PVerb{` already matches the innerBrace. I am not sure, why this happens, so I modified the start pattern of the innerBrace not to match at the `\PVerb{` part:

For me, this works:

```
syn region MyTexZone start="\\PVerb{" end="}" containedin=TOP
syn region innerBrace start="\(\\PVerb\)\@<!{" end="}" transparent containedin=MyTexZone
```

Note, you shouldn't use a Syntax group that is already defined in the tex.vim syntax file. That makes it harder to debug what is happening.

Comment: Interesting how you arrived at almost the same solution! The matching is explained in the help: The contained groups will also match in the start and end patterns of a
region.  If this is not wanted, the "matchgroup" argument can be used
|:syn-matchgroup|.  The "ms=" and "me=" offsets can be used to change the
region where contained items do match.